# Почему Timer ругается на ImageView?

Tags: android, java

После того как пройдет 5 секунд, должен запуститься процесс анимации. Но взамен я получаю ошибку. Был вариант использовать runUiThread, но после обновы его не стало почему-то... Что скажете?

```
public class ToastService extends Service {
    private ImageView imageViewYota,imageViewBanner;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        imageViewBanner=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageViewYota=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageViewYota.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageCreate(imageViewBanner, Gravity.BOTTOM, R.drawable.auto_banner);
        imageCreate(imageViewYota, Gravity.CENTER,R.drawable.yota);
        TimerYota();
    }

    public void imageCreate(ImageView imageView, int winParamsGravity, int drawableImage) {
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams WinParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, -3);

        WinParams.gravity = winParamsGravity;
        imageView.setImageResource(drawableImage);
        frameLayout.addView(imageView, WinParams);
        windowManager.addView(frameLayout, WinParams);
    }

    public void TimerYota(){
        Timer timer=new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            int time=0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                time++;
                if (time==(5)) AnimYota();
            }
        },0,1000);
    }

    public void AnimYota(){
        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Animation animationShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.show_hide_yota);
                animationShow.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        imageViewYota.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        imageViewYota.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                imageViewYota.startAnimation(animationShow); //ВОТ ТУТ ОСТАНОВИЛСЯ ОСТАНОВИЛСЯ КОМПИЛЯТОР!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}

android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6094)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4320)
            at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10940)
            at android.view.View.startAnimation(View.java:16798)
            at com.example.AutoTablet.ToastService$2.run(ToastService.java:87)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно `Handler` в GUI-потоке создать и выполнять анимацию там:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            Animation animationShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.show_hide_yota);
            animationShow.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    imageViewYota.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    imageViewYota.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            imageViewYota.startAnimation(animationShow); 
      };
   };

public void AnimYota(){
    Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: А собственно ошибка то в чем,я понять не могу. THread не имееет доступа к UI или что?

Comment: Я раньше просто использовал метод runUIThread и норм было, а щас нет его

Comment: @asdasdasd да, из второстепенных потоков нельзя обращаться к элементам GUI.

Comment: @asdasdasd а вот почему runUIThread не работает больше, сложно сказать )

Comment: А пчоему тогда нелезья просто через таймер простым вызовом метода селать?